# I want to create ssh tunnel to access API

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have the scenario:

My local machine is srv1
The jump server is srv2
The target server on which API is running is srv3

So, there is an API that is running and accessible on srv3 at port 88. I could not access it directly from my local machine ie srv1.

But, I could ssh to this srv3 from sev2 which is a jump server. And I could ssh to the sev2 from my own server ie srv1.

Now, is there a way I could access the API running on srv3 at port 88 from my machine ie srv1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `srv3:88` is accessible from `srv2`, you can do a simple tunnel. On `srv1`, execute

```
ssh -L 8888:srv3:88 srv2
```

(where `8888` is arbitrary number greater or equal than `1024`). While the connection lasts, any connection to `srv1:8888` will be transmitted to `srv3:88`.

If you need the tunnel to be on `srv1:88` instead (where `88` is an arbitrary number under `1024`), you will need to run the above command as root, since only root can bind on privileged ports.

If `srv3:88` is only accessible from `srv3`, then you'll need to make it a bit more complex:

```
ssh -oProxyCommand="ssh srv2 -W %h:%p" -L 8888:localhost:88 srv3
```

(You can also add `-N` option to not run the shell - so instead of stopping the tunnel with `exit` or `^D`, you would do it with `^C`).

Comment: superb! worked like a charm. thanks. Now i understood why i was not able establish a tunnel because the srv3:88 was accessible only from srv3. Thanks for your help.